# .mht file looking for local resources

Tags: base64, doc, mhtml

I'm auto-generating .doc files (.mht really) according to this [tutorial](http://sebsauvage.net/wiki/doku.php?id=word_document_generation).

Generated files work great locally but not on other computers as the file is requesting the header to be loaded from my local path instead of using the base64 version that is embedded. The main content is loading fine. Here's the generated [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14184604/my_file.doc).

I can't find the reason for this behaviour. Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT**

Turned out that the problem was caused by unnecessary carriage return and line feed characters at the beginning of my base64 strings.